# Not passing user input into array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a problem passing user input into an array. I am supposed to be taking the user input and depending on the type, pass it into a defined array, and then pass that into a method that gives the total of the array. The problem is the total is showing as "O", which is making me believe that the data is not in the array. Any advice would help.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class WestonPASS9
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input1;
        int size1;
        int enterint;
        double enterdouble;
        float enterfloat;
        long enterlong;
        int[] arrayint = new int[0];
        double[] arraydouble = new double[0];
        float[] arrayfloat = new float[0];
        long[] arraylong = new long[0];



        System.out.println("What data type are you using? (Int, Double, Float, Long)");
        input1 = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("How many numbers will you be entering?");
        size1 = keyboard.nextInt();

        if(input1.equals("Int"))
        {
         arrayint = new int[size1];
         for(int i=0;i<size1;i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Integer");
            enterint = keyboard.nextInt();}
            getTotal(arrayint);

        }
         if(input1.equals("Double"))
        {
         arraydouble = new double[size1];
         for(int i=0;i<size1;i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Double");
            enterdouble = keyboard.nextDouble();}

        }
         if(input1.equals("Float"))
        {
         arrayfloat = new float[size1];
         for(int i=0;i<size1;i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Float");
            enterfloat = keyboard.nextFloat();}

        }
         if(input1.equals("Long"))
        {
         arraylong = new long[size1];
         for(int i=0;i<size1;i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Long");
            enterlong = keyboard.nextLong();}

        }
      }
      public static int getTotal(int[] x)
          {
          int total = 0;    
           for (int index = 0; index < x.length; index++)
           {
            total += x [index];         
           }         
           System.out.println("Total: "+total);
           return total;
          }



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,  here is the code if anyone needs the answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WestonPASS9
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input1;
        int size1;
        int enterint;
        double enterdouble;
        float enterfloat;
        long enterlong;
        int[] arrayint;
        double[] arraydouble;
        float[] arrayfloat;
        long[] arraylong;



        System.out.println("What data type are you using? (Int, Double, Float, Long)");
        input1 = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("How many numbers will you be entering?");
        size1 = keyboard.nextInt();

        if(input1.equals("Int"))
        {
         arrayint = new int[size1];
         for(int index =0; index < arrayint.length; index++)
         {
            System.out.println("Enter Integer " + (index + 1) + ": ");
            arrayint[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
         }
         for (int index = 0; index < size1; index++)
            System.out.print(arrayint[index]+" ");
            getTotal(arrayint);
            getAverage(arrayint);
            getHighest(arrayint);
            getLowest(arrayint);

        }
         if(input1.equals("Double"))
        {
         arraydouble = new double[size1];
         for(int index =0; index < size1; index++)
         {
            System.out.println("Enter Double " + (index + 1) + ": ");
            arraydouble[index] = keyboard.nextDouble();
         }
          for (int index = 0; index < size1; index++)
            System.out.print(arraydouble[index]+" ");
            getTotal1(arraydouble);
            getAverage1(arraydouble);
            getHighest1(arraydouble);
            getLowest1(arraydouble);

        }
         if(input1.equals("Float"))
        {
         arrayfloat = new float[size1];
         for(int index =0; index <size1; index++)
         {
            System.out.println("Enter Float " + (index + 1) + ": ");
            arrayfloat[index] = keyboard.nextFloat();
         }
         for (int index = 0; index < size1; index++)
            System.out.print(arrayfloat[index]+" ");
            getTotal2(arrayfloat);
            getAverage2(arrayfloat);
            getHighest2(arrayfloat);
            getLowest2(arrayfloat);


        }
         if(input1.equals("Long"))
        {
         arraylong = new long[size1];
         for(int index =0;index <size1; index++)
         {
            System.out.println("Enter Long" + (index + 1) + ": ");
            arraylong[index] = keyboard.nextLong();
         }
          for (int index = 0; index < size1; index++)
            System.out.print(arraylong[index]+" ");
            getTotal3(arraylong);
            getAverage3(arraylong);
            getHighest3(arraylong);
            getLowest3(arraylong);


        }
      }
      public static int getTotal(int[] x)
          {
          int total = 0;    
           for (int index = 0; index < x.length; index++)
           {
            total += x [index];         
           }         
           System.out.println("Total: "+total);
           return total;
          }
     public static double getAverage(int[] x)
          {
           int total = 0;   
            for (int index = 0; index < x.length; index++)
            {
                total += x [index];         
            }        
           double average = (total/2.0);
           System.out.println("Average: "+average);
           return average;  
          }
      public static int getHighest (int[] x)
          {
           int highest = x[0];
           for (int index=1; index<x.length; index++)
           {
            if (x[index]>highest)
            highest=x[index];
           }
           System.out.println("Highest: "+highest);
           return highest;
          }
      public static int getLowest (int[] x)
          {
           int lowest = x[0];
           for (int index=1; index<x.length; index++)
           {
            if (x[index]<lowest)
            lowest=x[index];
           }
           System.out.println("Lowest: "+lowest);
           return lowest;
           }    





     public static double getTotal1(double[] x)
          {
          double total = 0; 
           for ( int index = 0; index < x.length; index++)
           {
            total += x [index];         
           }         
           System.out.println("Total: "+total);
           return total;
          }
     public static double getAverage1(double[] x)
          {
           double total = 0;    
            for (int index = 0; index < x.length; index++)
            {
                total += x [index];         
            }        
           double average = (total/2.0);
           System.out.println("Average: "+average);
           return average;  
          }
      public static double getHighest1 (double[] x)
          {
           double highest = x[0];
           for (int index=1; index<x.length; index++)
           {
            if (x[index]>highest)
            highest=x[index];
           }
           System.out.println("Highest: "+highest);
           return highest;
          }
      public static double getLowest1 (double[] x)
          {
           double lowest = x[0];
           for (int index=1; index<x.length; index++)
           {
            if (x[index]<lowest)
            lowest=x[index];
           }
           System.out.println("Lowest: "+lowest);
           return lowest;
           }




     public static float getTotal2(float[] x)
          {
          float total = 0;  
           for ( int index = 0; index < x.length; index++)
           {
            total += x [index];         
           }         
           System.out.println("Total: "+total);
           return total;
          }
     public static double getAverage2(float[] x)
          {
           float total = 0; 
            for (int index = 0; index < x.length; index++)
            {
                total += x [index];         
            }        
           double average = (total/2.0);
           System.out.println("Average: "+average);
           return average;  
          }
      public static float getHighest2 (float[] x)
          {
           float highest = x[0];
           for (int index=1; index<x.length; index++)
           {
            if (x[index]>highest)
            highest=x[index];
           }
           System.out.println("Highest: "+highest);
           return highest;
          }
      public static float getLowest2 (float[] x)
          {
           float lowest = x[0];
           for (int index=1; index<x.length; index++)
           {
            if (x[index]<lowest)
            lowest=x[index];
           }
           System.out.println("Lowest: "+lowest);
           return lowest;
           }    




     public static long getTotal3(long[] x)
          {
          long total = 0;   
           for ( int index = 0; index < x.length; index++)
           {
            total += x [index];         
           }         
           System.out.println("Total: "+total);
           return total;
          }
     public static double getAverage3(long[] x)
          {
           long total = 0;  
            for (int index = 0; index < x.length; index++)
            {
                total += x [index];         
            }        
           double average = (total/2.0);
           System.out.println("Average: "+average);
           return average;  
          }
      public static long getHighest3 (long[] x)
          {
           long highest = x[0];
           for (int index=1; index<x.length; index++)
           {
            if (x[index]>highest)
            highest=x[index];
           }
           System.out.println("Highest: "+highest);
           return highest;
          }
      public static long getLowest3 (long[] x)
          {
           long lowest = x[0];
           for (int index=1; index<x.length; index++)
           {
            if (x[index]<lowest)
            lowest=x[index];
           }
           System.out.println("Lowest: "+lowest);
           return lowest;
           }    





 }
```